# how to convert address to lines and file names on windows with PDB files?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windbg, callstack, pdb-files

I have PDB files and callstack like this

```
#1 - wseclient.dll+0x121170
#2 - wseclient.dll+0x120024
#3 - wseclient.dll+0x25fbf
```

I used to use add2line.exe to convert address to lines, but it doesn't work on vs2019, does anybody know is there any other way to convert address on callstack?

Answer (score 0):

### Setting up an example

Some sample code to be compiled with Visual Studio 2019:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
public:
    __declspec(noinline) static int one()
    {
        throw std::exception("maximize debugging fun");
    }
};
__declspec(noinline) int main()
{
    return Test::one();
}
```

This will create the following call stack when being run in WinDbg:

```
0:000> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr      
...
02 00affa6c 00661316     CallStackDecodingExample!Test::one+0x1d [C:\...\CallStackDecodingExample.cpp @ 6] 
...
```

And we can use some calculations to get the numbers back and forth:

```
0:000> ? CallStackDecodingExample!Test::one+0x1d
Evaluate expression: 6689037 = 0066110d
0:000> ? CallStackDecodingExample
Evaluate expression: 6684672 = 00660000
0:000> ? CallStackDecodingExample+0x110d
Evaluate expression: 6689037 = 0066110d
0:000> ln 0066110d
 [C:\...\CallStackDecodingExample.cpp @ 6] 
(006610f0)   CallStackDecodingExample!Test::one+0x1d   |  
(00661110)   CallStackDecodingExample!main
```

Given the debugger was able to resolve the PDBs correctly, we now have the expected result. Let's try to get this without a debugging session, i.e. neither with live debugging nor with crash dump analysis, but by PDBs + text input.

### Getting the address from a DLL + PDB

In WinDbg, use "Open dump file", although you don't have a crash dump file. Instead, open the DLL (wseclient.dll or CallStackDecodingExample.exe for this example).

Then use [`ln`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ln--list-nearest-symbols-):

```
0:000> ln CallStackDecodingExample+0x110d
 [C:\...\CallStackDecodingExample.cpp @ 6] 
(004010f0)   CallStackDecodingExample!Test::one+0x1d   
|  (00401110)   CallStackDecodingExample!main
```

Comment: hi Thomas, sorry for updating late.
I tried open my dll with windbg and run command: ln wseclient.dll+0x766f9
but I got "Couldn't resolve error at 'wseclient.dll+0x766f9'.
do you know this error? thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you open wseclient.dll, or did you open something else? What is "my DLL"?

Comment: I opened wseclient.dll and it finally works.
thanks Thomas, you save my day.
and do you know if we can use the command line to do such thing?

Comment: Should be possible. Right out of my head `cdb -z wseclient.dll -c "ln wseclient.dll+xxx;q"`. Something like that